# Lenovo yoga 510 touchscreen not working

Tags: devices, touch-screen

I just got a Lenovo Yoga 510. I've [installed Fedora 25](http://symcbean.blogspot.co.uk/2016/12/installing-linux-fedora-on-lenovo-yoga.html) (as dual boot with MSWindows). But the touchscreen isn't working in Wayland nor Xorg.

`xinput list` only shows the trackpad, keyboard, powerbutton and camera. No likely candidates seen in /proc/bus/input/devices, lspci, lsusb nor dmesg.

lsusb reports two devices (other than hubs): acer 5986:0711, which appears to be the webcam and amd 0438:7900. I've not been able to find a description for the latter. I don't see anything else which is obviously the trackpad (which is working fine) - so the AMD USB device might be that.

Under MSWindows, it seems the devices is handled by the WacomPen driver.

In Linux, running

```
modprobe wacom
modprobe wacom_w8001
xsetwacom --list devices
```

produces no output.

It does seem a little strange that not only is the device unsupported by Linux, but actually seems to be *invisible* to Linux.

While I don't believe I'm in a position to start writing device drivers, I would like to be able to capture as much information as possible about the hardware, if nothing else to be able to describe the issue.

Does anyone have any suggestions about where else I should be looking for information about the hardware (or a solution would be nice too ;))

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm looking for a convertible at an affordable price, and hit on this model as being very much suitable ; but seeing the non-working touchscreen would be a dealbreaker.... did you ever install any other distro to troubleshoot ?

Comment: With the current Ubuntu, it works up until the system suspends - after a wake from suspend its not responding (a full boot restores it). If that's good enough, I would definitely recommend it as a cheap, sturdy laptop.

Comment: Hmmm that sounds pretty inconvenient for something meant to be on-the-go.... ah well. Thanks for the advice!